# Elasticsearch - aggregation terms

Tags: elasticsearch

Есть "таблица" в Elasticsearch  , которая имеют вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тепер делаю запрос:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggregations": {
      "sport": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "prices.pharmacy.name"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

и получаю Ответ:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 30,
    "successful": 30,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1999,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "sport": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "docmorris",
          "doc_count": 1000
        },
        {
          "key": "apotheke.com",
          "doc_count": 999
        },
        {
          "key": "shop",
          "doc_count": 999
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы shop и online.com в одной "строке" было?

```
"aggregations": {
    "sport": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "docmorris",
          "doc_count": 1000
        },
        {
          "key": "shop-apotheke.com",
          "doc_count": 999
        },
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю у вас на поле _prices.pharmacy.name_  включен анализатор, который позволяет производить поиск по словам. Добавьте описание полей [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/indices-get-mapping.html).

Comment: при создании индекса поставьте полю index: not_analyzed

Comment: Если нужен анализатор, попробуйте _"field": "prices.pharmacy.name"_ заменить на _"script" : "doc['prices.pharmacy.name'].value"_ в настройках должны быть разрешены скрипты _script.inline: on_

Comment: Решение: index: not_analyzed.

Спасибо всем.

Comment: @Alex Andr будет время оформите в виде ответа на вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

т.к. вопрос часто встречающийся, напишу как делал я, сразу говорю всё вышеперечисленное делал через расширение для хрома Sense, для других случаев нужна коректировочка кода, отключать анализатор можно вот так

```
POST Здесь_имя_index
{"mappings": {
    "здесь_имя_type": {
        "_all": {
            "enabled": false
        },
            "properties": {
                "поле_без_индексации1":{
                    "type":"string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                },
                    "поле_без_индексации2":{
                        "type":"string",
                            "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    }
            }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Для поля `prices.pharmacy.name` в маппинге надо указать `type:keyword`.

В таком случае вся строка будет считаться единым целым и анализироваться без разбора на части.